# C# How to access a brother class from within a class function?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a code structured like the one below. I simplified it with just the strictly needed to pose the question.

I have a Parent class, which includes an Item1 class, Item2 class, Item1_to_Item2_relationship class. I must keep this structure for reasons not relevant to this problem.

How can I access a value in Item1 from Item2?
The code explains better what needs to be done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent parent = new Parent();

            // Adding item1 values
            Item1 item1_01 = new Item1();
            item1_01.id = "item1_01";
            item1_01.item1_code = "CODE_01";
            parent.items1.Add(item1_01);
            Item1 item1_02 = new Item1();
            item1_02.id = "item1_02";
            item1_02.item1_code = "CODE_02";
            parent.items1.Add(item1_02);

            // Adding item2 values
            Item2 item2 = new Item2();
            item2.id = "item2_01";
            parent.items2.Add(item2);

            // Adding relationships
            Item1_to_Item2_Relationship item1_to_Item2_Relationship = new Item1_to_Item2_Relationship();
            item1_to_Item2_Relationship.item1.id_alt = item1_01.id;
            item1_to_Item2_Relationship.item2.id_alt = item2.id;
            parent.Item1_to_Item2_Relationships.Add(item1_to_Item2_Relationship);

            item1_to_Item2_Relationship = new Item1_to_Item2_Relationship();
            item1_to_Item2_Relationship.item1.id_alt = item1_02.id;
            item1_to_Item2_Relationship.item2.id_alt = item2.id;
            parent.Item1_to_Item2_Relationships.Add(item1_to_Item2_Relationship);

            // How to make the code below return a List<string> with the values "CODE_01" and "CODE_02"?
            foreach (Item2 my_item2 in parent.items2)
            {
                my_item2.item1_codes;
            }


        }
    }

    class Parent
    {
        public List<Item1> items1;
        public List<Item2> items2;
        public List<Item1_to_Item2_Relationship> Item1_to_Item2_Relationships;

        public Parent()
        {
            items1 = new List<Item1>();
            items2 = new List<Item2>();
            Item1_to_Item2_Relationships = new List<Item1_to_Item2_Relationship>();
        }

    }
    class Item1
    {
        public string id;
        public string id_alt;
        public string item1_code;
        public Item1()
        {
            id = "";
            item1_code = "";
        }
    }
    class Item2
    {
        public string id;
        public string id_alt;
        public Item2()
        {
            id = "";
        }
    }
    class Item1_to_Item2_Relationship
    {
        public Item1 item1;
        public Item2 item2;

        public Item1_to_Item2_Relationship()
        {
            item1 = new Item1();
            item2 = new Item2();
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I would have to right a static function which receives a Parent parameter and do the logic there. But I believe there should be a better more intuitive way. How can I make the above code work?

Comment: Since the fields of `class Item1` are public, given an `Item1` object, code in an `Item2` method can just reference the field.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers you can access it directly. Since you are maintaining a relationship, I assume you want to do it via the relationship

```
            var test = new List<String>();            
            foreach (Item2 my_item2 in parent.items2)
            {
                foreach (var item in parent.Item1_to_Item2_Relationships)
                {
                    //implement your own equality comparision if it should be differernt
                    if (item.item2.id_alt == my_item2.id)
                    {
                        test.Add(item.item1.item1_code);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Few important points:

1. You are dealing with list and nested loops, the performance of the
   approach is not best.
2. To improve the performance the relationship data structure should be
   chosen wisely, is it possible to convert it to `Dictionary`, thus
   giving quicker lookup times.
3. The code currently will add blank string since you do not add the Code in the relationship, but you can always search for object using the id, that means another search in list, this is the reason I am saying that you might want to change the underlying data structure.
4. It might be better to store the individual objects also in a dictionary if their item code is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way to do this would be to pass in `parent` into the function in which `itemX` would need to access a property from `itemY`.

For instance:

```
class Item1
{
    public string id;
    public string id_alt;
    public string item1_code;
    public Item1()
    {
        id = "";
        item1_code = "";
    }
}
class Item2
{
    public string id;
    public string id_alt;
    public Item2()
    {
        id = "";
    }
    public void AccessItem1Prop(Parent parent) {
        string item1ID = parent.items1[0].id;
    }
}
```

You could also pass in `parent` to the individual items constructor and attach it to the item as an object property, but I'd avoid that approach if you can simply to keep things cleaner.

Comment: IMO, I think the approach of having sister objects access each other is not structurally a good idea. In theory, the two objects are distinct because they shouldn't be aware of each others' existence. It would normally be the job of the parent to manage its children.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of how the code is structured... but here's the simple answer.

You're adding two different item types to two different collections.

You're making a relationship item, that relates the two based on id.

Although your code screams help the idea is logical and a good way to relate items such as working with a database.

We can do this simply with Linq but I would rather stick closer to how you're writing the question.

First iterate your items like you're doing, then iterate your relationships.  Based on Id comparison you then iterate the other items and based on that final Id comparison you get your answer.

```
foreach (Item2 my_item2 in parent.items2)
{
    foreach (Item1_to_Item2_Relationship relatedItem in parent.Item1_to_Item2_Relationships)
    {
        if (my_item2.id == relatedItem.item2.id_alt)
        {
            foreach (Item1 item1 in parent.items1)
            {
                if (relatedItem.item1.id_alt == item1.id)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item1.item1_code);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Outputs
//CODE_01
//CODE_02
```

Answer (score -1):

'just do it'

```
var i1 = new Item1();
var i2 = new Item2();

i1.id = i2.id;
```

Now others will argue that you should use properties rather than public fields. But what you have at the moment allows you to do exactly what you want.